# EKEventStore saveEvent adding events a hour later

Tags: ios, iphone, timezone, nstimezone, ekeventstore

I believe this worked before but now when I add a event to my calendar when I am in time zone set to automatically or Louisville which is EDT, and I add an event that is EDT it adds it to my calendar a hour ahead.

I do this on another app that has events in CST, and when I add them to my calendar, it adds them just fine.  Is my code wrong or something?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:self.event.timeZone]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"];

    self.startDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.game.dateTime];
    self.endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:60*self.event.gameDuration sinceDate:self.startDate];
}


    - (void) addToCalendar
    {
        EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

        if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]){
            [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
             {
                 for (EKSource *source in eventStore.sources)
                 {
                     if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV || source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)
                     {

                         EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
                         event.title     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ vs. %@", self.game.awayTeam.team.name, self.game.homeTeam.team.name];
                         event.location = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", self.game.venue.name, self.game.venue.court];

                         event.startDate = self.startDate;
                         event.endDate = self.endDate;

                         [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                         NSError *err;

                         [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

                         if(err) {
                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                 [self showAlert:@"Error" desc:@"There was a problem adding this game to your calendar"];
                             });
                         }
                         else {
                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                 [self showAlert:@"Success" desc:@"Game added to your calendar"];
                             });
                         }
                         break;
                     }
                 }
             }];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out Apple uses their own timezone strings so I just did a translation from Windows Timezones to Apple when sending it via our API.

Comment: I believe this to be false.